# Does Capacitor require BOTH a Mac AND Android Studio

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, phonegap, capacitor

I have an HTML5 app I have developed using legacy code that includes jQuery and jQuery UI. The app was developed using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows. I create the ipa and apk files using PhoneGap. As of June 30th, Apple will no longer accept my app because it isn't using version 13 of the API AND it's using the deprecated UIWebView. Based on what I am seeing, PhoneGap probably isn't going to provide support for either of those so I need a new solution.

I'd like to migrate to Capacitor, but the [requirements](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/getting-started/dependencies/) list both Xcode 11 (with CocoaPods (?) & the CL tools) AND Android Studio if I want a cross-platform app.

Am I misunderstanding how this works? I'm coming from PhoneGap where I could build apps for both platforms by building an HTML5 app and adding a config file. (I don't need plug-ins, it's a simple app but I do have 10k installs I would like to continue to support.) Requiring both dev environments seems to defeat at least some of the advantages of "cross-platform" development.

I am using [this guide](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/cordova/migrating-from-cordova-to-capacitor/) from Ionic. If there is another that is better please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you build locally you need a Mac for iOS and android studio for android. That’s the same as if you use phonegap or cordova locally.
You can build online using build services such as ionic appflow